# How do I fix low resolution on my Canon T5i?

Tags: canon, resolution

I went to get some prints and they were super blurry. I asked the photo center workers and they said it is because the resolution is way too low, so I can't print anything bigger than 5x7. I'm not a photography expert, so I have NO idea how to fix this problem. How do I get a higher resolution?

Comment: You should edit your original question to include this new information.

Answer (score 1):

In the camera menu go to 'image quality'. Arrow through to the level of resolution desired, then press set.